# Atmega328P Wake up from Power Down mode using a edge Triggered Interrupt

Tags: arduino, arduino-uno, atmega, arduino-c++

Snapshot from the ATmega328P datasheet:

[image]

According to the above section of the ATmega328P datasheet, only a Level or Pin change interrupt should wake up the CPU from Power Down Sleep Mode.

However, in the following code, a rising edge is being used to wake up the CPU from Power Down Mode.

```cpp
#include <LowPower.h>

const byte led_pin = 8;
const byte interrupt_pin = 2;
volatile byte state = LOW;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  pinMode(led_pin,OUTPUT);
}

void loop() {
  // the interrupt must be attached each loop
  attachInterrupt(digitalPinToInterrupt(interrupt_pin), interrupt_routine, RISING);
  LowPower.powerDown(SLEEP_FOREVER,ADC_OFF,BOD_OFF); // sleep until interrupt
  detachInterrupt(digitalPinToInterrupt(interrupt_pin)); // remove interrupt

  // the usual wake routine that turns on the LED
  if (state == HIGH) {
    digitalWrite(led_pin, HIGH);
    delay(500);
  }

  if (state == HIGH){
    state = LOW;
    digitalWrite(led_pin,LOW);
  }
}

void interrupt_routine() {
  state = HIGH;
}
```

Code taken from "[Arduino Interrupts with PIR Motion Sensor](https://makersportal.com/blog/2019/5/27/arduino-interrupts-with-pir-motion-detector)".

**I don't understand how this code is working.**

Answer (score 5):

The Atmel datasheet make people believe that you can only use LOW interrupts to wake up the MCU when it is in sleep mode. It has however been long confirmed that you can use any type of interrupt (Rising edge / Falling edge / Low level / any logical change) to wake up the ATmega328P from sleep mode. There was a mistake on Atmel's datasheet. This was confirmed and documented by Nick Gammon on his post on [Interrupts](https://www.gammon.com.au/interrupts).

Comment: Your answer needs more upvotes. Indeed, the link you posted contains an official response from Atmel about the datasheet error.